# Why does auto import generate relative path for root node modules in PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: node.js, ide, phpstorm, webstorm

My project structure:

```
/website
   /node
     /node_module <<-- library root
     /type_src  <<-- ts files
     /src  <<-- compiled js files
```

I used to be able to auto import root node modules like this:

/type_src/store/BaseStore.ts:

```
import {observer} from "mobx-react/native";
@observer
class BaseStore{

}
```

But recently, the auto import generates relative paths for these node modules:

```
import {observer} from "../../node_modules/mobx-react/index";
@observer
class BaseStore{

}
```

The only way to generate `import {observer} from "mobx-react/native";` is to wait for that red light bulb to show up, which isn't as convenient.

I've created another project and it works fine, but I have no idea why this project suddenly has this problem. Can anyone help me figure out this problem?

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./src",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For references: same question on JetBrains Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35197

Answer (score 0):

Based on referenced link, it is (already fixed) bug in webstorm.

Solution - upgrade to 2017.1 or higher